# How to construct a SplashScreen from a loaded image file, not a project resource

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen

How would you inherit System.Windows.SplashScreen so has to enrich this class by the possibility of constructing itself on loading an image at a precise path.

By definition System.Windows.SplashScreen offers only these two constructors:

```
public SplashScreen(string resourceName);
public SplashScreen(Assembly resourceAssembly, string resourceName);
```

As I still feel ill at ease with WPF, I don't have the single idea where to start modifications ?

Or should I redesign completely my own SplashScreen class ?

Answer (score 0):

might not answer you are looking for. but how about adding that image (which you have precise path) into your local resource and you can reuse SplashScreen without redesign

Just read [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.splashscreen.aspx) here, WPF SplashScreen seems to quite poor, in WinForm you could add text (where you could display status message and stuff).

Comment: Because the splash changes depending on the customer. And as the SplashScreen is created at the first line of App(), I don't have access to the configuration, so I cannot know which customer launches the App... It looked nice to install one image file, different for each customer and load this one on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

why not installing a resource assembly containing the image for each customer and reference or load it with `Assembly.Load()` at runtime?

you can even automate the build of such a resourceassembly using Mono.Cecil in a tool

Answer (score -1):

Create a window called splashscreen and make it singleton like:

```
public partial class Splashscreen:Window
{
 static Splashscreen splashscreen;
    public Splashscreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static void ShowSplashScreen()
    {
        splashscreen = new Splashscreen();
        splashscreen.Show();
    }

    public static Splashscreen SplashScreen { get { return splashscreen; } set { splashscreen = value; } }
```

Do all the customizations you want in the xaml like showing status, progress,image etc.

read app.config to get the client details and show it according to the user.

call splashscreen.showsplashscreen() in the first line of your void main() or in your appstartup.
once the application is fully loaded destroy splashscreen by calling splashscreen.splashscreen.close() either sync or async.